# STC Network blocks my android application

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, network-programming

While using STC network connection which blocks to open my android app. Anyone have an idea about this?

This happens from the countries like Kuwait. Is this is network related issue or device specific? This happens only for a few of our users....